# jmf mp3 plugin not play some categories of mp3 files

Tags: java, swing, mp3, jmf

I tried to play mp3 file using JMF with JMFMP3plugin it works with some format of mp3 files but not for all.
  The mp3 file is MPEGLayer means it plays well but MPEG-audio means it shows error like below,

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 15
    at codecLib.mpa.k.a(Unknown Source)
    at codecLib.mpa.k.do(Unknown Source)
    at codecLib.mpa.Decoder.decode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.media.codec.audio.mpa.JavaDecoder.process(JavaDecoder.java:327)
    at com.sun.media.BasicFilterModule.process(BasicFilterModule.java:322)
    at com.sun.media.BasicModule.connectorPushed(BasicModule.java:69)
    at com.sun.media.BasicOutputConnector.writeReport(BasicOutputConnector.java:120)
    at com.sun.media.SourceThread.process(BasicSourceModule.java:729)
    at com.sun.media.util.LoopThread.run(LoopThread.java:135)
```

The player has been displayed but the file not play. I'm using JMF code for play and createPlayer etc,...

Thanks in Advance..,

Comment: *"I tried to play mp3 file using JMF with JMFMP3plugin it works with some format of mp3 files but not for all."* Yep.  What's your question?

Comment: I did play mp3 file with jmf mp3 plugin. It works but some type of encoding file e.g. mpeg-audio encoding not supported. It shows ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException

Comment: Yes, you already wrote that.  Do you understand what a *question* is?  **Hint** so far I've asked you two questions, you've asked none.

Comment: The mp3 file encoding type is mpeglayer3 means it works fine. But other then mpeglayer3 encoding type like mpeg-audio not works.

Comment: Ya sure. How can i play the mp3 file if the encoding type is other then mpeglayer3?

Comment: Short answer: Find a decoder that supports that encoding.